# ¿se puede programar en c normal en la edición Comunity de VS?

Tags: c, windows, vs

Normalmente programo en CodebloCks para windows pero para hacer que el programa pidiese permisos de administrador vi que lo más fácil era usar la edición Comunity de VS. Lo que pasa es que en la página para descargarlo pone programar en c/c++ pero una vez descargas el intalador no te da la opción de programar en c solo en c++. ¿alguien sabría como hacer para que te deje programar en c?

Answer (score 1):

De la [documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160) ...

### C++ in Visual Studio

> Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) refers to the C++, C, and assembly language development tools and libraries available as part of Visual Studio on Windows.

Por la tanto la respuesta a tu pregunta es **Si se puede**.

Para compilar y ejecutar un proyecto debes crearlo normalmente en el IDE seleccionando la opcion C++ pero luego debes renombrar tus archivos y cambiar la extension `.cpp` por la `.c`

Una version simplificada consiste en usar el compilador de la linea de comandos que provee Visual Studio que se llama `cl`. De acuerdo a lo que dice esta [guia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Y como lo hago esque imagino que se puede pero lo he intentado varias veces y soy incapaz . Cuando creo un proyecto no me deja elejir la opción de c y si cojo la de visual c++ que es la que más se parece me da errores al poner el int main y al usar funciones de c como fopen();

Comment: Te he puesto una respuesta con detalles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453648/228368).

Comment: El problema de los errores es por la extensión del archivo. Actualicé la respuesta para reflejar eso y otras cosas más.

Answer (score 1):

Para programar en C/C++ en la edición Community de Visual Studio tienes que bajarte el instalador, en [esta](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/vs/community/) página está el enlace de descarga.

Cuando lo instales te encontrarás en una vista donde podrás seleccionar el conjunto de herramientas de desarrollo que quieres instalar. Necesitarás las que ponen "*Desarrollo para el escritorio con C++*".

Si ya lo tienes instalado y no instalaste las de C++, entonces tendrás que volver a ejecutar el instalador y modificar la instalación, tiene un botón para eso, e instalar las herramientas que te falten.

En Visual Studio la diferencia entre programar en C o C++ estará en las bibliotecas que incluyes en tu código, aunque por defecto será C++. Pero por esa parte no te procupes, incluye las bibliotecas de C y empieza a practicar.

Para el resto del proceso de crear proyectos y compilar necesitarás leer tutoriales, tienes uno de inicio [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-a-standard-cpp-program-cpp?view=msvc-160) que te servirá.

Si lo que quieres es realizar pruebas simples mientras aprendes C++ utilizando solamente entrada y salida por consola (stdin/stdout), hay algunas herramientas online que son útiles como esta de [aquí](https://onecompiler.com/cpp). Hay varias más, algunas incluso mucho mejores, pero para empezar te sirve.

Comment: Lo he descargado como tu me has dicho y he creado un proyecto. Al añandir el .cpp de c++ he cambiado el nombre a main.c y después he añadido las librerias stdio y stdlib sinembargo no me deja usar por ejemplo fopen que se supone que viene con stdio y me dice que use la función fopen_s que imagino es de c++ como arreglo eso?

Comment: fopen_s no es c++, es una versión nueva de fopen más segura, igual que el resto de funciones de cadena. Es una recomendación que te hace el compilador, pero puedes usar las antiguas si no recuerdo mal, definiendo la constante _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: **fopen_s** es la misma función, pero con mejoras de seguridad. Por eso el compilador te pone "Consider using fopen_s instead". Al inicio del fichero puedes poner una línea **#pragma warning(disable:4996)**, o definir el símbolo _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Hay más información de cómo hacerlo [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis).